# How to add nesting to an items in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So if I want to remove nesting from array items I can definitely do it:

```
var nestedArrs = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];
var denestedArr = [].concat.apply([], nestedArrs);
console.log(denestedArr) //prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

but what about if I need to go backwards and add nesting?

```
var unnestedArr = [7, 8, 9, 10];
var nestedArr = [] ? // Say I want to add nesting to every other item in arr
console.log(nestedArr); //so I wanted it to print [[7], 8, [9], 10]
//& nested Arr needs to be based upon the starting unnestedArr.
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/ had questions that included concepts like this in older JS curriculum.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var unnestedArr = [7, 8, 9, 10];

var nestedArr = unnestedArr.map(function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 === 0 ? [ item ] : item;
});

console.log(nestedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308582/how-to-add-nesting-to-an-items-in-array-javascript#answer-45308610), I would suggest a [function programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
If you don't like "hard-coding" the "every other" decision criterion , you could make a ["mask"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

```js
const unnestedArr = [7, 8, 9, 10];

// Here we define which items should be nested
const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0;
const nestCriterion = (item, index) => isEven(index);
const shouldBeNested = unnestedArr.map(nestCriterion); // = [true, false, true, false];

// Next we perform the nesting to the items we identified above
const nestedArr = unnestedArr.map((item, index) => {
    return shouldBeNested[index] ? [ item ] : item;
});

// Alternatively, we could've just used "one big function" like this:
const nestedArr2 = unnestedArr.map((item, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
         return [ item ];
    }
    else {
        return item;
    }
});

// If we wanted to modify the array in place (instead of creating a new one)
// we could've used .forEach instead of .map and modified (mutated)
// elements of interest (e.g. by wrapping them in an array)

console.log(unnestedArr, nestedArr, nestedArr2);
```

Here's an implementation on [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/xequhey/edit?js,output)